# Converting JSON response to a struct in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm new in swift programming and am trying to get the user data in JSON format from the server and then "paste" it into a struct :

**This is my api :**

```
app.get('/getUser/:username',(req,res)=>{
    let user = req.params;
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE username = ? ";
    mysqlConnection.query(sql,[user.username],
    function(err, rows){
        if(!err){    

       res.send(JSON.stringify({"userID" : rows}));
}
 else {
console.log(err)
         }
    });
});
```

**This is the JSON response:**

```
{
    userID =     (
                {
            email = test;
            id = 1;
            money = 200;
            password = test;
            username = test;
        }
    );
}
```

**This is my apiCall function :**

```
    class func  getUser(username :String)
    {          
            let url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/getUser/"+username
            Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler : { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success( _):
                    // I want to append the user struct by the user data collected from JSON
                    print(response.result.value!)

                case .failure(let error):
                    print (error)
                }

            })                   
        }
```

**And this My struct :**

```
struct user {
    var id : String
    var username : String
    var password : String
    var email : String
    var money : String        
}
```

I Tried to create an array in my MainPageViewController and then append it but I don't know how :

```
class MainPageViewController: UIViewController {
    var currentUser : String?
    var userData = [user]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        API.getUser(username: currentUser!)
        print(currentUser!)

        super.viewDidLoad()
     //   API.getUserID(username: currentUser!)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: Best way would be with codeable...

Comment: Your question is ambiguous because from the dictionary output you cannot determine if the type of `id` and `money` is `String` or `Int`

Comment: Hey louay baccary please share the answer/solution you went with, currently, I am stuck at the same stage

Answer (score 3):

Well best way to do would be with Codeable:

```
let data: YourJSONData

struct User: Codable {
    var id: String
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var email: String
    var money: String
}

let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
```

**EDIT**

To answer your further question, just use it like this:

```
static func getUserByUsername(_ username: String) {
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/getUser/" + username

    Alamofire.request(url).responseData(completionHandler : { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success( let data):

            do {
                let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(Base.self, from: data)
            }
            catch {print(error)}

        case .failure(let error):
            print (error)
        }

    })
}

struct Base: Codable {
    let userID: [User]
}

struct User: Codable {
    var id: String
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var email: String
    var money: String
}
```

Comment: and how can i use it ? where to put this code and how to relate it with my api

Comment: Well anywhere you want... Now it is a native Struct representing a User...

Comment: This throws a `DecodingError` if you wouldn't ignore it.

Comment: Well its exactly the same way you wrote above?!? @Sh_Khan

Comment: i did `responseData` not  `responseJSON` , plus this is not a suitable  place for `struct`

Comment: Shit, I am sorry... Didn't see this issue... I hade copied his Version and edited it in a playground, to show him where to use it... Thanks four you're info...

Comment: Yes I was wandering why I did get an DownVote... Could you upvote it again? Maybe someone did come across and red that this will fail... @Sh_Khan

Comment: Yes, I did because the code cannot work. Please see my first comment. `user` will be `nil`. Don't ignore decoding errors.

Comment: @vadian Now I get what you mean... The code would work, but it doesn't fit to his DataModel, because of the userID Array is missing?!? That needed to be downvoted in your opinion?

Comment: @Sh_Khan It was vadian... He takes it very correctly... ;-)

Comment: Sorry, programming is a very precise subject and a failing code doesn't help a newbie like the OP.

Comment: @vadian Thats correct, but we are just helping people in a minimum of time, without a compiler for free, getting their problems solved for years now... So I didn't thought we need to be so extremely correctly... I have updated my answer :-) Could I get my upvote back now?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let userID: [User]
}

struct User: Codable {
    let email: String
    let id, money: Int
    let password, username: String
}

do {
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:data)
    users = res.userID
 }
 catch {
    print(error)
 }
```

and change Alamofire from `responseJSON` to `responseData`

---

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseData(completionHandler : { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success( let data):
        // I want to append the user struct by the user data collected from JSON
        print(response.result.value!)
        do {
            let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:data)
            userData = res.userID
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

    case .failure(let error):
        print (error)
    }

})
```

Comment: I didn't understand , my problem is i want to convert the data from JSON to strings then append it to my struct

Comment: Well JSON in Swift is just a String... You have to serialize it to a Struct, and then you can use it as a Struct Wherever you want to...